# How to check the user input is an integer or not with Scanner?

Tags: java, input, integer, java.util.scanner

I want the country codes are integer that input by the user. I want an error message to be show when user inputs a code which is not an integer. How can I do this? The program is to ask user to enter country name and country code. In which user will input the country code. But if user inputs a character I want a message to be shown saying Invalid Input.

```
System.out.println("Enter country name:");                     
countryName = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter country code:");            
int codeNumber = in.nextInt(); 
in.nextLine();
```

Comment: You make yourself aware by reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

If the input is not an `int` value, then `Scanner`'s `nextInt()` (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) for API) method throws [InputMismatchException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), which you can `catch` and then ask the user to re-enter the 'country code' again as shown below:

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean isNumeric = false;//This will be set to true when numeric val entered
  while(!isNumeric)
     try {
        System.out.println("Enter country code:");
        int codeNumber = in.nextInt(); 
        in.nextLine();
        isNumeric = true;//numeric value entered, so break the while loop
        System.out.println("codeNumber ::"+codeNumber);
  } catch(InputMismatchException ime) {
     //Display Error message
     System.out.println("Invalid character found,
            Please enter numeric values only !!");
     in.nextLine();//Advance the scanner
  }
```

Comment: why `new Scanner(System.in)` is inside the while loop?

Comment: Yes, no need, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing it, is reading a line for the numbers as you did with the name, and then checking witha  Regex (Regular Expression) to see if contains only numbers, with the matches method of string, `codeNumber.matches("\\d+")`, it returns a boolean if is false, then it's not a number and you can print your error message.

```
System.out.println("Enter country name:");                     
countryName = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter country code:");            
String codeNumber = in.nextLine(); 
if (codeNumber.matches("\\d+")){
    // is a number
} else {
    System.out.println("Please, inform only numbers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead check `hasNextInt` then call `nextInt`

```
int codeNumber;

System.out.println("Enter country code:");

if(in.hasNextInt())
{
    codeNumber = in.nextInt();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Code !!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, by first getting the input as a string, then try to convert the string to an integer, then outputs an error message if it can't:

```
String code= in.nextLine();
try
        {
          // the String to int conversion happens here
          int codeNumber = Integer.parseInt(code);
        }
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
          System.out.println("Invalid Input. NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own custom exception class, then use regex to check if the input string is an integer or not.

`private final String regex = "[0-9]";`

Then, check if the input follows the regex pattern.

```
if (codeNumber.matches(regex)) {
    // do stuff.
} else {
    throw new InputMismatchException(codeNumber);
}
```

You can use build in InputMismatchException if you are not creating your custom exception handler.